# RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am getting this runtime error here:

```
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument mat1 in method wrapper_CUDA_addmm)
```

However, all the tensors I've created here are on cuda. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lin = nn.Linear(5,1)
        self.trans = nn.Transformer(nhead=1, num_encoder_layers=1, d_model=5)

    def forward(self, x):
        tgt = torch.rand(4, 5).to(device)
        y = self.trans(x, tgt)
        out = self.lin(y)
        return out

device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = MyModel()
model.to(device)
model.eval()

src = torch.rand(4,5)
out = model(src)

print(out)
```

Also, is there some pytorch command I can use to list all tensors on a device?

Comment: Seems like I was able to fix the problem by defining tgt in "init" but I'm not sure why this fixes the issue

Answer (score 1):

`src` is on cpu.

```
# src = torch.rand(4,5)
src = torch.rand(4,5).to(device)
```